# Removing White Space: C#

Tags: c#, .net, regex, whitespace, infix-notation

I am trying to `remove white space` that exists in a `String input`. My ultimate goal is to create an infix evaluator, but I am having issues with parsing the input expression.

It seems to me that the easy solution to this is using a `Regular Expression` function, namely `Regex.Replace(...)`

Here's what I have so far..

```
infixExp = Regex.Replace(infixExp, "\\s+", string.Empty);
string[] substrings = Regex.Split(infixExp, "(\\()|(\\))|(-)|(\\+)|(\\*)|(/)");
```

Assuming the user inputs the infix expression (2 + 3) * 4, I would expect that this would break the string into the array `{(, 2, +, 3, ), *, 4}`; however, after debugging, I am getting the following output:

```
infixExp = "(2+3)*7"
substrings = {"", (, 2, +, 3, ), "", *, 7}
```

It appears that the white space is being properly removed from the infix expression, but splitting the resulting string is improper.

Could anyone give me insight as to why? Likewise, if you have any constructive criticism or suggestions, let me know!

Comment: Regex is not suited for parsing nested structures...

Comment: `It appears that the white space is being properly removed from the infix expression`  If that is the case, than why are you talking about removing whitespace?

Comment: @leppie: To me, it looks like the only purpose of the regex is to tokenize the input. The parsing of the nested structure happens later, based on the tokens. If that really is the case, using a regex for tokenizing should work.

Comment: @leppie .NET actually has some very elegant regex constructs to do that. however, the OP doesn't seem to be parsing nested structures but is only splitting the string into individual tokens... which I think regular expressions are perfectly fine for.

Comment: If it is not homework or for learning purposes, I would say use [NCalc](http://ncalc.codeplex.com/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution I was looking for thanks to all of your replies.

```
// Ignore all whitespace within the expression.
infixExp = Regex.Replace(infixExp, @"\s+", String.Empty);

// Seperate the expression based on the tokens (, ), +, -, 
// *, /, and ignore any of the empty Strings that are added
// due to duplicates.
string[] substrings = Regex.Split(infixExp, @"([()+*/-])");
substrings = substrings.Where(s => s != String.Empty).ToArray();
```

By doing this it seperates the characters of the String into parts based on the regular mathematical operators (+, -, *, /) and parenthesis. After doing this it eliminates any remaining empty Strings within the `substrings`

Answer (score 4):

If a match is at one end of the string, you will get an empty match next to it. Likewise, if there are two adjacent matches, the string will be split on both of them, so you end up with an empty string in between. Citing [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ze12yx1d.aspx):

> If multiple matches are adjacent to one another, an empty string is inserted into the array. For example, splitting a string on a single hyphen causes the returned array to include an empty string in the position where two adjacent hyphens are found [...].

and

> If a match is found at the beginning or the end of the input string, an empty string is included at the beginning or the end of the returned array.

Just filter them out in a second step.

Also, please make your life easier and use verbatim strings:

```
infixExp = Regex.Replace(infixExp, @"\s+", string.Empty);
string[] substrings = Regex.Split(infixExp, @"(\(|\)|-|\+|\*|/)");
```

The second expression could be simplified even further:

```
@"([()+*/-])"
```

Answer (score 1):

Please, ditch Regex. There are better tools to use. You can use `String.Trim()`, `.TrimEnd()`, and `.TrimStart()`.

```
string inputString = "   asdf    ";
string output = inputString.Trim();
```

For whitespace within the string, use `String.Replace`.

```
string output2 = output.Replace(" ", "");
```

You will have to expand this to other whitespace characters.

Comment: I still don't see the advantage over having multiple plain string replacements for space, tab and line breaks over a simple `\s+`.

Comment: @m.buettner "Advantage" might be a bit subjective, but I see your point. IMO, Regex is not the correct tool for the job, but in an isolated case, it can work.

Answer (score 1):

```
var result = Regex.Split(input, "(\\d+|\\D)")
              .Where(x=>x!="").ToArray();
```

Comment: That would drop the tokens though, wouldn't it?

Comment: @m.buettner what are the tokens? I think he just wants to convert the input string (an expression) into an array of all the chars except spaces.

Comment: I mean, your result wouldn't contain the operators, right? It would only leave the numbers.

Comment: @m.buettner you're right, I didn't read it carefully, looks like we have to use `Regex.Split` here, I updated my answer with `Regex`.

Answer (score 1):

[m.buettner's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18494247/933416) is correct. Also consider that you can do this in one step. From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/byy2946e.aspx):

> If capturing parentheses are used in a Regex.Split expression, any
>   captured text is included in the resulting string array.

Therefore, if you include the whitespace in the split pattern but outside the capturing parentheses, you can split on it as well but not include it in the result array:

```
var substrings = Regex.Split("(2 + 3) * 7", @"([()+*/-])|\s+");
```

The result:

```
substrings = {"", ( , 2, "", +, "", 3, ), "", "", *, "", 7}
```

And your final result would be:

```
substrings.Where(s => s != String.Empty)
```

Comment: Very neat! There is a slight difference in results though: a space between numbers would cause two numbers/tokens in your case while it would result in only one number/token with the OP's two-step approach.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just remove the white spaces and then split the string with normal string handling functions? Like this...

```
string x = "(2 + 3) * 4";
x = x.Replace(" ", "").Replace("\t",""); //etc...
char[] y = x.ToCharArray();
```

Why bother making this more complicated than it needs to be?

Comment: I guess it's nice to keep the numbers in one token.

Comment: `ToCharArray` wouldn't work, because it would rip apart numbers with more than one digit.

Comment: OK, so replace that part with regex to capture whole numbers instead of digits. You can still simplify the removal of white space, and have much more readable and reliable code.

Comment: @Jasmine: And how is it more readable to have multiple `Replace` calls instead of a single one? And how is it more reliable to have to manually take into account all possible whitespaces instead of using a standardized set?

Comment: Daniel, because Regex expressions are harder to read than explicit replacements. Regex expressions get complicated really quick. It is easy to get them slightly wrong.

Comment: @Jasmine: We are not talking about regular expressions in general. We are talking about `Regex.Replace(infixExp, @"\s+", string.Empty);` vs `x = x.Replace(" ", "").Replace("\t",""); //etc...`

Comment: @DanielHilgarth seconded. Jasmine, your argument implies that one should never ever use regex, because there is a danger of misusing them. In this particular case, regular expressions offer a very concise, readable and elegant solution, and are probably even faster than doing four replacements (or a few dozen actually if the input can contain arbitrary Unicode).

Comment: That argument could be applied to any code structure that is more complicated than another. That doesn't make it an invalid argument. It is a matter of personal preference anyway.

Answer (score 0):

A non-regex solution would probably be [String.Replace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk49wtc1.aspx) - you could simply replace " ", "\t", and other whitespace with the empty string "".

Comment: How is that simpler than just regex-replacing `\s` with the empty string?

Comment: I must admit I don't have a suitable answer. Upon rereading my question, it does seem inadequate. I apologize.