# Dropdown list with white spaces

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu, whitespace, trim

I have a dropdownlist binded like this.

```
 string qissuetype = "select trim(empname),empfullname from empmast where " + ListBox1.SelectedValue + "<3 order by empname";
 OdbcDataAdapter adpState = new OdbcDataAdapter(qissuetype, con1);
 DataSet ds = new DataSet();
 adpState.Fill(ds);                
 drpResponsible.DataSource = ds;
 drpResponsible.DataTextField = "trim(empname)";
 drpResponsible.DataValueField = "empfullname";
 drpResponsible.DataBind();
```

I have trimmed the empname while binding, but still it shows leading and trailing white spaces if any exists.

Can anyone help me doing this?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `TRIM()` is not supported, then `LTRIM(RTRIM(empname))` will achieve the same result.

Also, You can try these links:

1) [Remove Trailing Spaces and Update in Columns in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14781999/remove-trailing-spaces-and-update-in-columns-in-sql-server)

2) [How to remove white space characters from a string in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14211346/remove-white-spaces-of-a-string-in-sql-server-not-work)

3) [Remove all spaces from a string in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10432086/removes-all-white-spaces-of-a-string-in-sql-server)

Hope you get the solution, Thanks...

Answer (score 1):

sql, unfortunately, sometimes keeps all kinds of special characters that are very hard to remove. Try the solutions with regex here [Removing White Space: C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18494181/removing-white-space-c-sharp).

Also if you are using another language, like I am using hebrew, sometimes even that is not enough and the regex needs to be [a-zA-Z] with your lang letters.